# I don’t know how to get data in laravel correctly by linking the data in this database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, relationship

In this figure, the remaining tables are linked to the datainfo table. I need to retrieve the entire table data from the datainfo table.
[In this picture I have shown the tables themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcMul.jpg)

Comment: refer https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

Comment: This link helped me thank you but how can I determine the total amount on the same date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Eloquent Models for each table and define Relationships among them. This is the Correct Laravel Way.

Let's assume Your `datainfo` table represents your Datainfo model,
Your `cars` table represents Car model. Same as `washtypes` and `boxes`.

then depending on your relation type defined the relation in Datainfo model.

```
class Datainfo extends Model
{

    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
    }
}
```

You also can use `hasOne` instead of `hasMany` for one - to one relation

Similarly, create relation defining functions as `washtypes()` and `boxes()`.

Then To get Datainfo with all related data using something like think in your controller

```
return Datainfo::with('cars','washtypes','boxes')->get();
```

Alternatively, you can get the count

```
return Datainfo::with('cars','washtypes','boxes')->count();
```

To get a count on a date

```
return Datainfo::with('cars','washtypes','boxes')->where('created_at',$date_var)->count();
```

If you only want Datainfo that has relation with cars, washtypes or boxes:

```
return Datainfo::has('cars','washtypes','boxes')->where('created_at',$date_var)->count();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel eloquent join clauses, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins
For total amount in same day
You can use eloquent sum and group by methods based on the date